# expected class-name before '{' token error

Tags: c++, class, templates, inheritance, header

I'm getting the error "expected class-name before '{' token" in my C++. I am trying to inherit the avlTree class into the word search class, but it is not working.

```
#ifndef WORDSEAR_H
#define WORDSEAR_H

#include <string>
#include "avlTree.h"

class wordSearch: public avlTree  
{                                  <----error right here 
public:
//functions are here
private:
};

#endif
```

this is avlTree.h

```
#ifndef AVLTREE_H
#define AVLTREE_H

template <class myType>
struct nodeType {
myType  keyValue;
nodeType<myType>    *left;
nodeType<myType>    *right;
};

template <class myType>
class avlTree
{
public:
//functions are here
private:
};
#endif
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`avlTree` is a class template, you need to specify the template argument for it:

```
class wordSearch: public avlTree<something>
```

According to your intent, you might make `wordSearch` class template too:

```
template <typename myType>
class wordSearch: public avlTree<myType>
```